# How to kill these PHP process safely?

Tags: php, linux, process, pid

I have installed php5 in ubuntu and WordPress. It can run after installed. But after few days I've found there are lots of process and occupied a lot of memories.
I try to use

```
ps -aux | grep www-data
```

and found about 30 processes like this.

```
www-data  5066  0.0  0.0 131664   780 ?        S    16:20   0:00 /usr/sbin/php5-fpm --fpm-config /etc/php5/fpm/main.conf
```

I tried to

```
kill -9 pid
```

and it didn't work, more process appears again.
So could you tell me how to kill them safely and I don't want to my vps' memory occupied by it.

Answer (score 1):

> and it didn't work, more process appears again

Really? While I'd expect more processes to appear the one you killed should go away.

If you want to stop all of these then shutdown the daemon, I don't know how it's configured on your machine, but here I'd do....

```
/etc/init.d/php-fpm stop
```

But htat's not the way to fix the problem of "I've found there are lots of process and occupied a lot of memories". You should start by doing proper traffic analysis and profiling the code.

Answer (score 0):

Try here, I think its the same problem :)

[How to stop www-data's Apache processes?](https://serverfault.com/questions/89616/how-to-stop-www-datas-apache-processes)

"Apache running as www-data is the default in Debian Lenny. You might be confusing a single 'parent' apache process (running as root) with apache 'children' doing HTTP request processing (running as www-data). Both 'parent' and 'children' processes should look like they were started with /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start (when you ps aux | grep apache), and the only difference is the process owner.

To control init startup scripts you could use sudo sysv-rc-conf (sudo aptitude install sysv-rc-conf if you don't have it - it is just an easy curses-like Perl wrapper for init scripts)." -Chronos

So each process is child process dealing with http requests, if yo really want to kill them either kill the process with sudo kill PID or maybe  /usr/sbin/apache2 -k stop.

Tom

Comment: There is also one process that belongs to root and not www-data. This one is needed to bind to port 80 but will not actually do anything else for safety reasons.

Comment: i do not want to stop nginx or apache ,just think the memory it used may be too large.could you give me a solution that can optimize it or let the memory it occupied be fewer?

Comment: Apache is never going to be super memory efficient. If you want to really minimize your memory usage, maybe use another web server such as lighttp http://www.lighttpd.net/. If your hell-bent on streamlining Apache, maybe try http://wiki.joyent.com/display/gen/Tuning+Apache.

Comment: Also take not of the bottom of this page, http://soporte.ideasmultiples.com/index.php?_m=knowledgebase&_a=viewarticle&kbarticleid=51. Basically you can tune your Apache to have less spare children, this will save memory. Hope this helps :)

Answer (score -1):

There is 100% nothing wrong with what you are seeing. PHP is a module being run by Apache which is controlled by the user `www-data`. What you are seeing is normal behavior. And the bulk of adjustments to me made to improve performance are connected to Apache configs & not so much PHP settings.

If you want to better control this behavior, there are two places to make adjustments.

**1. Adjust the PHP Memory Limit:** Open up your php.ini file which should be located in `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini` and edit the option
    called `memory_limit`. It should be set to 64M or 32M. But that is
    basically the MAX limit for memory any PHP process—which is tied to
    each Apache2 process (see below)—can use.  So if you run WordPress &
    it wants to run any process with 32M RAM, no problem.  If it needs
    more the script will fail & your Apache2 error log located at
    `/var/log/apache2/error.log` will fill with errors.

**2. Adjust Your Apache Config to Suit Your Needs:** Since PHP is a module running in Apache, the more Apache processes you have running the more memory will be eaten up.  If you have a standard Apache2 install open up this file & look around: `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`.  Specifically here are the settings I always adjust in a standard install.

- **Timeout:** This is the timeout between a request being made by the client to the server & the server fulfilling that request. In my experience the setting of 300 seconds (5 minutes) is too high. I adjust this to 120.
- **KeepAlive:** I always keep this on as it helps Apache use memory & resources better. It basically means an Apache child process won't
  kill itself if a client is still requesting content.  That way one
  process can flow data & then safely die after it has done it's job.
- **MaxKeepAliveRequests:** This is directly connected to `KeepAlive`.  And I adjust this based on server needs.  For development
  environments I keep this low. Let's say 3 or 4.  For production
  environments I tend to feel `KeepAlive` is only useful for about 1/3
  of connections. So I set this to about 24 or 32.  But it memory is a
  concern, I would keep this low as the more `KeepAlive` processes you
  have running the more clients you have running & the more RAM you
  have used per process.
- **KeepAliveTimeout:** This is basically a measurement of how fast one can load a page on your site.  Think about it: Why keep a connection
  alive past the time it takes for a client to get the content for one
  page? In my experience a setting of 2 seconds to 5 seconds is good.
  But when it veers up to 5 seconds to render a page, it means that
  something is really choking the underlying system.  So to me that is
  a sign to re-evaluate code & clean up resource intensive coding.

  Next go to the `mpm_prefork_module` area. This is how I setup my development environment; this is for a low traffic site.

> ```
> <IfModule mpm_prefork_module>
>   StartServers           8
>   MinSpareServers        8
>   MaxSpareServers        8
>   ServerLimit           16
>   MaxClients            16
>   MaxRequestsPerChild 2000
> </IfModule>
> ```

Basically this sets all the limits & parameters for a basic Apache install. I believe each parameter should be self explanatory, but here is my breakdown.

- **StartServers:** How many child servers startup immediately under Apache.
- **MinSpareServers:** The minimum amount of child servers to keep in reserve.
- **MaxSpareServers:** The maximum amount of child servers to keep in reserve.
- **ServerLimit:** The top limit on the how many child servers can exist.
- **MaxClients:** The maximum amount clients that can exist at any given moment.
- **MaxRequestsPerChild:** This setting helps kill of child processes after a certain number of requests. This helps prevent memory leaks because technically child processes can run on forever until the next Apache2 restart. A safeguard I like to have in place so I can sleep at night even when a developer deploys sloppy code.

Hope this helps!

Comment: No, it's not running as a php module. Tweaking the apache config will have no direct impact on it.

Comment: Welp, I got nothing else. Hopefully someone can learn from my answer anyway.